# Is there any acceptable MSE for regression?

Tags: networking, neural-network, regression

I know you guys must have seen this kind of question s many time, but let me explain my problem. I have MSE less than 0.00008 in regression model which has scale 0.1-0.9 for data. I don't want to make another model to compare, I just want to know if this rate is acceptable or not. Also, my data is Network traffic which has a unit in Byte.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you please post the R-squared value from the regression? I calculate this as "1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" and use it to tell me the fraction of the dependent data variance that is explained by the model - for example, if the R-squared value is 0.95, I interpret this to mean that the model explains 95% of the dependent data variance. R-squared is exact for straight lines and approximate for other models, and gives me the same understanding of the modeling whether the units are micro-grams or light-years.

Comment: my R-squared is 0.990, and what do you mean by units? you mean my dataset unit?

Comment: I meant "units of the dependent variable", and part of my meaning was that R-squared itself has no units.

Comment: my dependent variable is Byte, but this MSE and R-squared I got it after rescaling my data to 0.1-0.9.

Comment: If the Mean Squared Error is 0.00008 on data scaled 0.1 to 0.9, with an R-squared of 0.99, given no other information I would think you are unlikely to find a different model that would perform significantly better. This is probably as close as practical to the most accurate model you can make of the data without additional information, in my personal opinion.